# Virtual Box on an non-intel Mac

Tags: macos, virtualbox

is it possible to install VirtualBox on a non-intel Mac ?

My configuration : G5 with Mac OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No as VirtualBox does not emulate the CPU but virtualizies it as [described by Oracle](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Virtualization).

You would need to find Virtual PC or Bochs (I have used both in the past) or others in a list from [www.macwindows.com](http://www.macwindows.com/emulator.html)

However now getting an extra second hand intel box might well be the easiest thing to do and would definitely provide the faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't unfortunately.  See the first line of the prerequisites on the [virtualbox support pages here](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions)